# Is it safe to save important credentials in local settings of an Windows 8 store app?

Tags: windows-8

I just want to save one my credentials in my app, which I would be using very frequently. So I'm currently saving it in my app's local settings. But I just want to know if it is really safe to save that data there?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's safe using `Windows.Security.Credentials`

"The great advantage that **`Credential Locker`** brings to your app is that it stores the user credentials in a secure location, and **the credential information is encrypted when it’s stored on disk.** "